# How do I hide Filesystem.CopyDirectory window?

Tags: c#, directory, filesystems, copy

I have this piece of C# code which copies my entire `tempdir` to my `folderdir`. How can I get this copy screen to be hidden? Currently it's just showing underneath the main window & I can see it perfectly, yet I want it so that you can't see the progress on the copying process.

```
label4.Text = "Extracting...";
Shell32.Shell sc = new Shell32.Shell();
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempdir);
Shell32.Folder output = sc.NameSpace(tempdir);
Shell32.Folder input = sc.NameSpace(tempdir + "ZipFile.zip");
output.CopyHere(input.Items(), 256);
File.Delete(templocation + "ZipFile.zip");

new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer().FileSystem.CopyDirectory(tempdir, _
folderdir, true);

label4.Text = "Cleaning up...";
Directory.Delete(tempdir, true);
```

If you don't know what I mean just comment it & I'll post a screenshot with some markings as to what I want hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `4` in the argument for `CopyHere`:

```
output.CopyHere(input.Items(), 4);
```

According to the [docs for the CopyHere method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this specifies to not display the progress dialog.

Comment: I see, I thought it was this part which was giving the progress dialog: `new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Computer().FileSystem.CopyDirectory(tempdir, folderdir, true);`

Comment: Turns out it was the CopyHere method as you said. Thanks :) By the way, correct me if I'm wrong here, but if I wanted (for example) the options from 4 & 16, I just add the numbers together and use `output.CopyHere(input.Items(), 20);` correct?

Comment: @Yorrick I think adding them will work.  You could also try the `or` operator: `4 | 16`